# jsf login page redirect error

Tags: jsf, primefaces

i am developing jsf using primefaces and jpa, and my screen is not redirecting to main page still exist in login page without display.

My web.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>Cation</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>login.xhtml</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.localizationContext</param-name>
    <param-value>resources.application</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <description>State saving method: 'client' or 'server' (=default). See JSF Specification 2.5.2</description>
    <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
    <param-value>client</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <description>
    This parameter tells MyFaces if javascript code should be allowed in
    the rendered HTML output.
    If javascript is allowed, command_link anchors will have javascript code
    that submits the corresponding form.
    If javascript is not allowed, the state saving info and nested parameters
    will be added as url parameters.
    Default is 'true'</description>
    <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.ALLOW_JAVASCRIPT</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <description>
    If true, rendered HTML code will be formatted, so that it is 'human-readable'
    i.e. additional line separators and whitespace will be written, that do not
    influence the HTML code.
    Default is 'true'</description>
    <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.PRETTY_HTML</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.DETECT_JAVASCRIPT</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <description>
    If true, a javascript function will be rendered that is able to restore the
    former vertical scroll on every request. Convenient feature if you have pages
    with long lists and you do not want the browser page to always jump to the top
    if you trigger a link or button action that stays on the same page.
    Default is 'false'
</description>
    <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.AUTO_SCROLL</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
</web-app>
```

My faces-config.xml file

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<faces-config xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_1_2.xsd"
    version="1.2">
    <managed-bean>
        <managed-bean-name>home</managed-bean-name>
        <managed-bean-class>com.cation.action.LoginAction</managed-bean-class>
        <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>      
    </managed-bean>
    <navigation-rule>
        <navigation-case>
            <from-outcome>home_page</from-outcome>
            <to-view-id>/pages/homePage.xhtml</to-view-id>
        </navigation-case>
    </navigation-rule>
</faces-config>
```

my login.xhtml

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3c.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.prime.com.tr/ui">
<h:head>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="themes/bluesky/skin.css" />
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <center>
    <p:panel header="Login Form" style="width: 350;">
        <h:form>
            <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="2">
                <h:outputLabel for="#{home.username}" value="UserName"/>
                <h:inputText value="#{home.username}" label="UserName"></h:inputText>
                <h:outputLabel for="#{home.password}" value="Password"/>
                <h:inputSecret value="#{home.password}"></h:inputSecret>
                <h:commandButton type="submit" value="Login" action="#{home.validateUser}"></h:commandButton>
            </h:panelGrid>
        </h:form>
    </p:panel>
    <div><h:messages ></h:messages></div>
    </center>
</h:body>
</html>
```

index.jsp file

```
<jsp:forward page="login.xhtml"></jsp:forward>
```

And my login action file

```
package com.cation.action;

import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;
import javax.persistence.Query;

import logon.Users;

public class LoginAction {

    private String username;

    private String password;

    private static final String PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME = "Cation";

    private static EntityManagerFactory factory;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public String validateUser() throws Exception {
        factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME);
        EntityManager em = factory.createEntityManager();
        // Read the existing entries and write to console
        Query q = em.createQuery("SELECT u FROM Users u where u.Login='"+username+"'");
        List<Users> userList = q.getResultList();
        Users user = (Users) userList.get(0);

        if(user == null){
            return "error";
        }
        /*// Create new user
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        Users user = new Users();
        user.setName("Tom Johnson");
        user.setLogin("tomj");
        user.setPassword("pass");
        em.persist(user);
        em.getTransaction().commit();

        em.close();*/
        return "home_page";
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

The problem is when i am logging using username and password it shows success in action but it is not redirecting to home page still exist in same page without any display and url shows like localhost:8080/Cation/login.xhtml

Can anyone plz help me to solve it

Comment: Your Faces Servlet url mapping is /faces/*. so you should call the page localhost:8080/faces/login.xhtml to run your application in Faces Conntext. Furthermore you should have a home_page.xhtml page since your action returns to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. return `"home_page?facesRedirect=true"` instead of `return "home_page";`
2. I would suggest login method like this:

```java
  public void login() throws IOException {
     FacesContext       context;
     HttpServletRequest request;
     ExternalContext    externalContext;         

     context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
     request = (HttpServletRequest) context.getExternalContext().getRequest();
     externalContext = context.getExternalContext();

     try { 
        // try to login
        request.login(username, password);
        // login successful so remember logged user
        loggedUser = userDao.findByName(username);
        externalContext.redirect(requestedURI);
     } catch (ServletException e) {
        // Unknown login
        context.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, ejbUtils.getMsg("msgUnknownLogin"), null));
        loggedUser = null;
     }
  }
```

I think that what you are doing will not affect user rights to see protected pages. It looks like test for existing user and password in database. It can be proper for desktop (java se) but not for web (java ee) applications, since in ee user can access page by it's address not by a menu or pushbutton.

Look for example of form based login.